# TeXStudio: newenvironment not recognized as "math-mode"; fix with cwl?

Tags: math-mode, environments, texstudio

For many of my papers I like to define a new environment `\newenvironment{numalign}{\begin{equation}\begin{aligned}}{\end{aligned}\end{equation}}` because I find it to be convenient shorthand.

TXS doesn't recognize this as being in "math-mode" however, so this messes up the autocomplete and inserts unnecessary $$ despite being in a math environment.

How can I resolve this? From what I could see it looks like a cwl file may present a solution, but I'm not quite sure how this works for a `\newenvironment` as opposed to `\newcommand`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can set the environment's treatment to the one of another `env` in the the cwl file by using the `\env` classifier
[image]
As in the example
[image]

So, for your specific case you should put

```
\begin{numalign}#\math
```

in the cwl-file to achieve the desired behavior:

[image]